# Как регулируется соответствие модификаторов при переопределении методов?

Tags: java, методы

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при переопределении методов модификаторы (`private`, `public`, `static`) подкласса должны обязательно прямо соотвествовать модификаторам суперкласса? Как регулируется соответствие модификаторов при переопределении методов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последовательность модификаторов по убыванию уровня закрытости: `private, default ,protected, public`.

Во время наследования возможно изменения модификаторов доступа в сторону большей видимости.
Private методы доступны только в классе в котором они описаны. В классе наследнике можно объявить такой же метод с тоже сигнатурой но другим модификатором доступа. Так делать считается плохой практикой. Protected методы можно расширить до public.